Pterodactyl Error while creating a server
{ object: 'user', attributes: [Object] },
    { object: 'user', attributes: [Object] },
    { object: 'user', attributes: [Object] },
  ],
  meta: {
    pagination: {
      total: 25,
      count: 25,
      per_page: 50,
      current_page: 1,
      total_pages: 1,
      left: {}
    }
  }
}
User ID: 23
Request body: {
  name: 'test12581eza',
  user: 24,
  egg: 18,
  docker_image: 'ghcr.io/pterodactyl/yolks:debian',
  startup: '/home/container/usr/local/bin/proot --rootfs="/home/container" --link2symlink --kill-on-exit --root-id --cwd=/ - -bind=/ proc --bind=/dev --bind=/sys --bind=/tmp /bin/sh',
  environment: {
    SERVER_MEMORY: 512,
    SERVER_CPU: 50,
    SERVER_JARFILE: 'server.jar',
    BUILD_NUMBER: 'latest'
  },
  limits: { memory: 512, cpu: 50, io: 500, swap: 0, disk: 2048 },
  allocation: { default: 'Finland1' },
  feature_limits: { databases: 1, backups: 1, split_limit: 1 },
  deploy: {
    locations: [ 1 ],
    dedicated_ip: false,
    port_range: { minimum: 4500, maximum: 5000 }
  }
}

MongoDB Error: Request failed with status code 422
MongoDB Error Stack: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 422
    at settle (D:\FeminiProject_Bot_v1\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2015:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\FeminiProject_Bot_v1\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:3131:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:529:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1400:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at Axios.request (D:\FeminiProject_Bot_v1\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:4262:41)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.execute (D:\FeminiProject_Bot_v1\commands\panel\createServer.js:91:42)
    at async Object.execute (D:\FeminiProject_Bot_v1\events\interactionCreate.js:18:9)
Disconnected from MongoDB

Here is my code:
https://pastebin.com/Wp1BMskR (serverCinfog.json)
https://pastebin.com/2xVz8bFV (Command File)
https://pastebin.com/NKFdvcut (User Creation Command) <-- Not really important
https://pastebin.com/TPUQfU5i (getUserIDfromEmail)
https://pastebin.com/333EUYdL (config.json)
The command should create a server, but before look into the database (mongodb) and check if the Limit is full.
